# Include region in localization selection in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

Is it possible to show to the user a certain set of localisation strings based on both the language selected and the region selected, where those two do not necessarily need to be compatible?

Let me give an example:
A user could choose English as their *iPhone Language*, but set China as their *Region*. Is it possible to show a certain localisation based on these two settings, that would then be different than both English and Chinese localisation, while at the same time leaving both English and Chinese localisations still available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, but you would need to implement your own substitution logic.

Use `NSLocale.currentLocale` to get you the locale information (Chinese, in your example) and `NSLocale.preferredLanguages` to get the array of languages, where the one you are interested in is the first one (English, in your example).

[NSLocale documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/currentLocale)

The reason you need to implement your own text substitution logic is that locale information is used primarily for formatting and language information is used to pull in the appropriate strings.